# Application Class Error

Tags: java, android, error-handling, instance, android-context

I created an applicaion class, now i am making its instance to use in other classes but i am facing the context null issue .

My Application Class:

```
public class CommonForApp extends Application {
private static CommonForApp sInstance;
private Utilities mUtilities = null;
private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mSharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(
                "com.myandroidapp.musicplayer", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mContext=this.getApplicationContext();
        mUtilities = new Utilities();
    }

    public CommonForApp() {
    }
    public static  CommonForApp getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null)
            sInstance = new CommonForApp();

        return sInstance;
    }

}
```

And declared it in AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
 <application
        android:name="com.android.musicplayer.datastorageandarraylistsaccesser.CommonForApp"
         android:largeHeap="true"
 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Music" android:allowBackup="true">
```

Now i am using it in other classes like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

         mApp=CommonForApp.getInstance();
         final List<GlobalSongDetails> s=mApp.getGlobalSongsList();

}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.musicplayer/com.android.musicplayer.Fragmentactivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177):    at com.android.musicplayer.datastorageandarraylistsaccesser.CommonForApp.makeGlobalSongsList(CommonForApp.java:127)
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177):    at com.android.musicplayer.datastorageandarraylistsaccesser.CommonForApp.getGlobalSongsList(CommonForApp.java:164)
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177):    at com.android.musicplayer.Fragmentactivity.onCreate(Fragmentactivity.java:156)
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
03-02 18:50:41.167: E/AndroidRuntime(16177):    ... 11 more
```

But if i make instance like this:

```
mApp=(CommonForApp) this.getApplicationContext();
```

I don't get any error.

Can anyone explain me what mistake i am doing ?

Thanks,in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in `getInstance()` you manually create instance of application object using `new`. You can't do that.
Only the system instantiates the application object.

If you want to work with singleton of the application you have to use it this way:

```
public class CommonForApp extends Application {

    private static CommonForApp sInstance;
    …

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sInstance = this;
        …
    }

    public static CommonForApp getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

Note that in some rare cases (e.g. in content provider) it can be null.

Comment: if i use object in this way ....will there be any issue like memory leak or any kind of problem ??

Comment: Application object is always a singleton in your app (it's just not accessible by any `getInstance()` method, but it's accessible via `context.getAppliactionContext()`). So by default you don't create any memory leak this way, but you can easily create a scenario where you leak memory. E.g. if you create some storage in the application, you have to be careful what you store there.

Comment: Storage of context you mean ??

Comment: Yes, something like that. There's million ways how to make a memory leak in android ;) But the construction is ok. It won't be null when you use it in activities/services/receivers.